# How to toggle a button with JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a button and it should increase the font size when clicked and if it's clicked again it should decrease the font. Also the value of the button should change to Increase Font / Decrease Font. So, basically I want to make the button toggle from increasing the font to 16px then decreasing to 14px if clicked again.

EDIT: I made it work but it doesn't keep repeating. Only works twice and that's it

**HTML**

```
<p id="increase">Lorem Ipsum.</p>

<input onclick="font()" style="background-color:#72cf26"  type="submit" value="Increase Font" id = "fontbutton"/>
```

**JS**

```
function font(){
  var fontsize = document.getElementById('increase');
  var fontbutton = document.getElementById('fontbutton');

  if (fontbutton.value == "Increase Font"){
    fontsize.classList.add("font16");
    document.getElementById('fontbutton').value = "Decrease Font";
  }else if (fontbutton.value == "Decrease Font"){
    fontsize.classList.add("font14");
    document.getElementById('fontbutton').value = "Increase Font";
    }
 }
```

**CS**

```
.font16{
   font-size:16px;
}
.font14{
   font-size: 14px;
}
```

Comment: `fontbutton.getElementById.value` doesn't make sense.  `getElementById` is a method, which you seem to understand as you use it correctly before this line.

Comment: How would I check the value of the button to make it work then in an if statement then?

Comment: are you ok to use jQuery?

Comment: What is default font size?

Comment: Remove the `.getElementById` from that line.  You don't need that.  You already have the button in the `fontbutton` variable.  Just call `.value` on it.

Comment: And actually `.value` is wrong here as the increase element is a `<p>` tag which do not have values.  They have `.innerHTML` and `.innerText`

Comment: Majed's answer is good but I wanted to add, as a best-practice, you should avoid names that are exactly descriptive of appearance, such as your class names `font14` and `font16`. Prefer something like `normal-text` and `large-text` — if you change your text sizes so for example your initial size is 16 and your increased size is 20 you would have CSS like `.font14 { font-size: 16px; }` - or you would have to go around changing the class everywhere it's used.

Comment: I changed my anwser to show how to change to `Increase / Decrease` button text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `fontbutton.value` instead of `fontbutton.getElementById.value` and remove the previous class using `fontsize.classList.remove` to add the new one using `fontsize.classList.add`:

```js
function font(){
     var fontsize = document.getElementById('increase');
     var fontbutton = document.getElementById('fontbutton');
     if (fontbutton.value == "Increase Font"){
          fontsize.classList.remove("font14");
          fontsize.classList.add("font16");
          fontbutton.value = "Decrease Font";
     }else if (fontbutton.value == "Decrease Font"){
          fontsize.classList.remove("font16");
          fontsize.classList.add("font14");
          fontbutton.value = "Increase Font";
     }
}
```

```css
.font16{
     font-size:16px;
}
.font14{
     font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<p id="increase" class="font14">Lorem Ipsum.</p>
<input onclick="font()" style="background-color:#72cf26"  type="submit" value="Increase Font" id = "fontbutton"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is complicated, JS directly offers a [toggle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle) method to add / delete a class and which returns a boolean value.
The only difficulty is that you should not forget to add `!important` to upgrade the size.

```js
const paragraphInc = document.getElementById('increase')
  ,   buttonSize   = document.getElementById('fontbutton')
  ;
buttonSize.onclick = () =>
  {
  buttonSize.textContent = (paragraphInc.classList.toggle('Size16'))
                          ? 'Decrease Font'
                          : 'Increase Font'
  }
```

```css
#fontbutton {
  background-color:#72cf26;
  padding: 7px 12px;
  }
#increase {
  font-size: 14px;
  }
.Size16 {
  font-size: 16px !important;
  }
```

```html
<p id="increase">Lorem Ipsum.</p>

<button id="fontbutton">Increase Font</button>
```

Comment: To be pedantic for a moment — it is the DOM `Element.classList` object that offers the `toggle` method, that is not a feature of Javascript

Answer (score 0):

The above requirement can be implemented using

`element.classlist.add` and `element.classlist.remove` functions.

**Here is a copy of the working code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <style>
            .font16{
                font-size:16px;
                background-color:#72cf26;
            }
            .font14{
                font-size: 14px;
                background-color:#72cf26;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="increase">Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        <button id="fontbutton" class="font14" onclick="toggleFont()">
            Increase Font
        </button>
        <script>
            function toggleFont() {
                var element = document.getElementById("fontbutton")
                var buttonText = element.innerHTML
                element.classList.remove("font14")
                element.classList.remove("font16")
                if(buttonText.indexOf("Increase") >= 0) {
                    element.classList.add("font16")
                    element.innerHTML = "Decrease font"
                } else {
                    element.classList.add("font14")
                    element.innerHTML = "Increase font"
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Output:**

[image]

**More information:**

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_class.asp

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var flag = true;
  $('.btn').click(function(){
      $(this).find('span').toggleClass('hidden');
      if(flag) {
       $('#increase').addClass('font16');
       $('#increase').removeClass('font14');
       flag = !flag;
      }else {
       $('#increase').removeClass('font16');
       $('#increase').addClass('font14');
       flag = !flag;
      }
     });
 });
```

```css
.font16{
   font-size:16px;
}
.font14{
   font-size: 14px;
}
.hidden {
      display: none;
     }

p{ font-size: 10px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="increase">Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    <button class="btn">
     <span>Increse Font</span>
     <span class="hidden">Decrese Font</span>
    </button>
```